# Compare the most recent row with the immediate previous in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am facing this problem where I need to compare the most recent row with the immediate previous one based on the same criteria (it will be **trader** in this case).

Here is my table:

```
ID  Trader  Price
-----------------
1   abc      5
2   xyz     5.2
3   abc     5.7
4   xyz      5
5   abc     5.2
6   abc      6
```

Here is the script

```
CREATE TABLE Sale
(
     ID int not null  PRIMARY KEY ,
     trader varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     price decimal(2,1),
)

INSERT INTO Sale (ID,trader, price)
VALUES (1, 'abc', 5), (2, 'xyz', 5.2),
       (3, 'abc', 5.7), (4, 'xyz', 5),
       (5, 'abc', 5.2), (6, 'abc', 6);
```

So far I am working with this solution that is not perfect yet

```
select 
    a.trader,
    (a.price - b.price ) New_price
from 
    sale a
join 
    sale b on a.trader = b.trader and a.id > b.ID
left outer join 
    sale c on a.trader = c.trader and a.id > c.ID and b.id < c.ID
where 
    c.ID is null
```

Above is not perfect because I want to compare only the most recent with the immediate previous on... In this sample for example

- Trader abc : I will compare only id = 6 and id = 5
- Trader xyz : id = 4 and id = 2

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Then the answer I provided should be working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use functions [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to join previous and next data. Unfortunately these function can only be used in `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clause, so you will need to use subquery to get the data you need:

```
SELECT t.trader, t.current_price - t.previous_price as difference
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.trader, 
        a.price as current_price, 
        LAG(a.price) OVER(PARTITION BY a.trader ORDER BY a.ID) as previous_price,
        LEAD(a.price) OVER(PARTITION BY a.trader ORDER BY a.ID) as next_price
    FROM sale a
) t
WHERE t.next_price IS NULL
```

Here in your subquery you create additional columns for previous and next value. Then in your main query you filter only these rows where next price is NULL - that indicates this is the last row for the specific trader.